# how to set the date and Time in php independent of computer date and Time

Tags: php, mysql

I want to set the date and time accurate in php or mysql which if I change my computer date and time, my web application should be still accurate and not changed, because I want to insert an accurate TimeStamp in my Database

Comment: when and why would you change your systems time to something that's not accurate?

Comment: actually I have web based application which is connected to a database and I want to deliver to my customer, I wanna ensure that if the date and time in my customer is not set accurately it should not affect to my web application

Comment: as long as the analysis of this application is mostly depend on the date and time

Comment: shipping as in "giving him access to the web-app" or as in "giving him the code"? in the first case, it doesn't matter what his time is, in the second one it's his responsibility to keep his system time accurate, and if he doesn't care about it, there's no reason for you to

Comment: isn't there any way to keep the time and date accurate, independent of user system date and time

Comment: Are you worried about time-zone differences? If so, use UTC time.

Comment: how can I use from UTC time in php

Comment: @MAO getting time-data from an internet-time-server, checking the difference and adding/substracting it wherever.you.do.something.with.times. which is a huge PITA to code and an enormous performance hit.

Comment: @MAO Use `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`.

Comment: @MAO If you use `time()` to get the timestamp to save in the database, it's based on UTC, not the computer's timezone.

Comment: @MAO You can also use the MySQL function `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` to get the current timestamp based on UTC.

Comment: How can I change the UTC timezone @Barmar
As I used that function in php It shows the Wrong Time according to my country timezone

Comment: That question makes no sense. UTC **is** a timezone.

Comment: I edited my comment read it again @Barmar

Comment: If you want to show the time according to your country timezone, use that timezone in `date_default_timezone_set`, not UTC. The point of using UTC is so that it will work the same no matter what country the user is in.

Comment: Oh that's my answer Thanks A lot @Barmar

Answer (score -1):

For date and time you use this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo date("M/d/Y h:i:s A");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

If you just want a timestamp, use this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo time();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33982351)